# Nativescript: tns device does not show emulator. ADB shows device

Tags: android, windows, adb, nativescript, nativescript-cli

I got the following issue.
I have my app written and tested on my personal android device, that worked fine. Now I want to test different android versions and created some AVDs and wanted to run the app. But it does not work. `adb devices` shows the ADV correctly. `tns device` does only show my hardware device.

Environment:
CLI: 6.0.3
Cross-platform modules: 3.0.4
Android Runtime: 6.0.1
iOS Runtime: 6.0.1
OS: Windows 10 1903

See the output of `tns device --log trace` here: [Github issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4952)

Comment: do you have enough RAM?  the files created in emulation are massive.  I couldn't get emulation working on my windows laptop and I think it's because it only has 4mb RAM.

Comment: No RAM does not seem to be the reason. I can start the emulator, play around with the device and also install and run the app manually

Comment: hmmm have you tried the {N} slack?  https://www.nativescript.org/slack-invitation-form

Comment: I don't. I will try there. Thank you!

Comment: @JamesSouth U mean 4GB right? :))

Comment: @yukashimahuksay haha yeah 4gb, I think 8 would be the minimum for this to work